# How can I include ng-model in autocomplete spring-boot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, spring-boot

In consultation mode I cannot return the dto values in the ng-model:

HTML code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-5 control-label"> Localité </label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <autocomplete ng-disabled="mode == 'read'"
            input-class="form control" options="referentielAdresses"
            display-property="localite" on-type="autoCompleteLocalite"
            on-select="get-localite" clear-input="false"
            ng-model="dto.localite"></autocomplete>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFLVi.jpg

JS code:

```js
//  autoCompleteLocalite

    $scope.autoCompleteLocalite = function(typed){
        if(typed!=""){
            $scope.dto.localiteRnvp = typed;
        }
    };
    $scope.getLocalite = function(selected){
        $scope.dto.localiteRnvp = selected.localite;
    }
```

How can I include ng-model midst autocomplete?

Comment: Please copy+paste the actual HTML in to the question, not an image of it

Answer (score 0):

Em... in $scope.getLocalite search for relative rows and show them into new block. On click on row update localiteRnvp value.

Comment: can you give me an example !